# Foreign Key constraint error occurs when when a model with navigation property added to the database

Tags: entity-framework

I have two tables,Employee and Department 
 **Employee**    
EmpId EmpName    DepID 
1     Jayaram      1   
2     Unni         1   
3     Hishan       2   
4     Dayeswar     2

**Department**

1  Medical
 2  Cleaning
 3  Saftey
 4  Canteen 
There are two models corresponding to these tables

```
public class EmployeeModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        public int DepId { get; set; }

        public virtual DepartmentModel Departments { get; set; }


    }

public class DepartmentModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int DepId { get; set; }
        public string DepName { get; set; }

    }
```

In EmployeeModel I put DepartmentModel as a navigation property.Here My problem is when I insert Employee table with EmployeeModel. I get the error as follows

> InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException HResult=-2146232060
>   Message=The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint "FK_dbo.EmployeeModels_dbo.DepartmentModels_DepId". The
>   conflict occurred in database "MvcApplication2.Models.Connect", table
>   "dbo.DepartmentModels", column 'DepId'. The statement has been
>   terminated. Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider ErrorCode=-2146232060
>
> Error occurs in **connect.Employees.Add(EmployeeModelObject);
>                   connect.SaveChanges();**

I hope some of my stack over flow brothers can get around my problem

Comment: When you add a new Employee, are you setting newEmployee.Departments property? Maybe you have to set only "FK" property, ie, DepId

Comment: Adding code could help. How are building you the EmployeeModelObject object?

Comment: According to your model, one *EmployeeModel* required one *DempartmentModel*. Are you specifying *EmployeeModelObject.DepId* (or *EmployeeModelObject.Departments*)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, you have a relationship between your tables and the FK value (column: DepId) you are inserting is not in the "DepartmentModel" table.

The way a FK works is it cannot have a value in that column that is not also in the primary key column of the referenced (DepartmentModel) table.

In order to fix, you need to set value to EmployeeModelObject.Departments with existing or new DepartmentModel object before saving EmployeeModel.

Sample:

```
using (var ctx = new CustomContext())
{
    EmployeeModel emp = new EmployeeModel() { EmpId = 1, EmpName="Name" }
    emp.Departments = new DepartmentModel() { DepId = 1, DepName = "D1" }
    ctx.EmployeeModels.Add(emp);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I was trying to add employee with  department ids  1,2,3, that is already there in the Department table ,please see my table vaues already given in the very beginning .Thank you for replay ,I expect further help